# check whether values lies between or not in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

These are my 2 tables

table 2:

| date_val | yr_num | yr_wk_num | day_wk_num | yr_wk_nm | day | mo_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20200808 | 2020 | 32 | 6 | 202032 | Saturday | 08 |
| 20200809 | 2020 | 32 | 7 | 202032 | Sunday | 08 |
| 20200810 | 2020 | 33 | 1 | 202033 | Monday | 08 |
| 20200811 | 2020 | 33 | 2 | 202033 | Tuesday | 08 |
| 20200812 | 2020 | 33 | 3 | 202033 | Wednesday | 08 |

table1:

| sku_id | dateval | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab124 | 20210603 | 10 |
| ab124 | 20210502 | 20 |
| ab123 | 20210606 | 30 |

Need to check sales is with in + or - 30% of 2 month avg sales

```
with CTE
as
(
    select * from table1  where dateval >= dateadd(mm, -2, dateval)
)
select dateval, sum(sales) as [Total Sales], avg(sales) as [Average Sales] from CTE group by dateval order by 1
```

I tried below also...

```
with CTE
as
(
    select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.dateval = t2.date_val  where t2.date_val >= dateadd(mm, -2, t1.dateval)

)
select dateval,sum(sales) as [Total Sales], avg(sales) as [Average Sales] from CTE group by dateval order by 1
```

here am doing filtering within  table1 but i need to use table 2 to get filtered for past two months and get avg sales.

Next, i need to do +30% to that result avg and -30% result avg and check whether my sales is withn avg sales( avg30% above or below) or not if yes '1' if not '0'

For Ex:

Historic 2 month avg sales 100.
(+30% of avg sales is 130)
(-30% of avg sales is 70)

if sales is 120. i need to check 120 lies  between 70 to 130.

please suggest me how to achieve

Comment: "Need to check sales ".  Nothing in your data is called `sales`, so I cannot follow the question.  Desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff, i edited table column name. now you can see sales.  This is for POC stage and i don't have desired data yet..i just got scenario

Comment: . . That helps, but you have to define what "2 month avg sales" means.

Comment: Its like historic 2 month avg sales @GordonLinoff i.e approximately 8 weeks

Comment: @GordonLinoff added example

Comment: @GordonLinoff any suggestion please